# Rad upload Java applet and z-index

Tags: java, html, css, applet

I'm using Rad upload for drag and drop upload. It's working perfectly except I'm having a problem with the z-index. I'm also using jquery UI on the site and the overlay doesn't cover the applet.

Any ideas on how to control the z-index. It would be nice if there where a setting like in flash where you control wmode. But I've tried z-index on the div that controls it and no result.

Comment: I will accept when the answers are helping me, I will not accept an answer that isn't giving me a solution. So far I haven't had any luck in answers that have helped me.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I been reading; there's no way to do that; maybe you could try with the gbiframe plugin for jQuery, but I didn't get comfortable with the readings about it, so I didn't even gave it a try.
That's why, most of the Java Applets users are moving to use Flash, because to that ones you could pass a param to be transparent, or something like that.

What I ended up doing was, to move or place the applet on a Modal Dialog, and open it when needed, so if the user opens an overlay, is because the applet is closed :-P

Cheers